# Формирование массивов из объектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Существует объект вида:

```
{
​  "01.09.2020": Object { "name1": 24, "name2": 14 }
  ​"02.09.2020": Object { "name1": 29, "name2": 10 }
  ​"03.09.2020": Object { "name1": 22, "name3": 1, "name2": 9 }
  ​"04.09.2020": Object { "name2": 5 }
  ​"05.09.2020": Object { "name1": 19, "name2": 5 }
}
```

Объект `Object { "name1": 24, "name2": 14 }` - может содержать различное количество и любое имя (name2) параметраов
Как бы так из него сделать, средствами jquery набор массивов

```
[
  [24, 29, 22, 0, 19],
  [14, 10, 9,  5, 5],
  [0,  0,  1,  0, 0]
]
```

То есть каждый массив должен соответствовать набору (name ов), если в объекте на какое либо число какой либо параметр отсутствует, то в массив ставиться 0
т.е [0, 0, 1, 0, 0] - Порядок чисел в массивах соответствует количеству и порядку дат.

Comment: Тут jQuery не причем. Нужно использовать обычный цикл на JS

Comment: @Node_pro почему не при чем? в jquery есть и вспомогательные методы, например `$.each` или `$.map`, итерирующие объекты. Вполне могут быть использованы при решении задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить задачу можно за один проход, для этого достаточно учитывать номер имен, и при появлении нового имени сразу добавлять массив заполненный нулями. Длина массива заранее известна и соответствует количеству дней.

Далее достаточно устанавливать значение по нужному индексу.

Пример реализации:

```js
const obj = {
  "01.09.2020": {
    "name1": 24,
    "name2": 14
  },
  "02.09.2020": {
    "name1": 29,
    "name2": 10
  },
  "03.09.2020": {
    "name1": 22,
    "name3": 1,
    "name2": 9
  },
  "04.09.2020": {
    "name2": 5
  },
  "05.09.2020": {
    "name1": 19,
    "name2": 5
  }
};

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur, index, arr) =>
  Object.entries(cur).reduce(({
    map,
    res
  }, [key, val]) => {
    if (!map.has(key)) {
      var counter = map.size;
      res[counter] = new Array(arr.length).fill(0);
      map.set(key, counter);
    }
    res[map.get(key)][index] = val;
    return {
      map,
      res
    };
  }, acc), {
    map: new Map(),
    res: []
  }).res;

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто, перебираем с помощью двух циклов данный объект и записываем результат в новый. Для того, чтобы получить номер, я обрезаю первых четыре символа, в случае, если вместо "`name`" будет другое слово, можно использовать `replace`.

```js
   const obj = {
      "01.09.2020": { "name1": 24, "name2": 14 },
      "02.09.2020": { "name1": 29, "name2": 10 },
      "03.09.2020": { "name1": 22, "name3": 1, "name2": 9 },
      "04.09.2020": { "name2": 5 },
      "05.09.2020": { "name1": 19, "name2": 5 }
    };
    
    const result = [];
    
    for(let date in obj ){
      for(let name in obj[date]){
        const nameNumber = name.substring(4);
        if(!result[nameNumber]){
           result[nameNumber] = [];
        }
        result[nameNumber].push(obj[date][name]);
      }
    }

    console.log(result);
```

Кстати, в вышеуказанном фрагменте первый элемент массива будет как `undefined`, так как массив начинается с "0", а ключи с "1". Если это проблема, можно исправить следующей строкой:

```
result.shift();
```

**Обновление 1:**

```js
const obj = {
  "01.09.2020": { "name1": 24, "name2": 14 },
  "02.09.2020": { "name1": 29, "name2": 10 },
  "03.09.2020": { "name1": 22, "name3": 1, "name2": 9 },
  "04.09.2020": { "name2": 5 },
  "05.09.2020": { "name1": 19, "name2": 5 }
};

const result = {};

for(let date in obj ){
  for(let name in obj[date]){
    if(!result[name]){
       result[name] = [];
    }
    result[name].push(obj[date][name]);
  
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Закиньте код в сниппет)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, хорошо)

Comment: Дело в том что, к примеру name1 - может быть абсолютно другого вида. например jip

Comment: @Андрей, другими словами, там могут отсутствовать нумерация?

Comment: да. могут быть любого вида

Comment: @Андрей, добавил обновление

Comment: если в объекте на какое либо число какой либо параметр отсутствует, то в массив ставиться 0

Comment: если нет значения на дату то 0

Comment: т.е [0,  0,  1,  0, 0]

Comment: Есть вариант получить массив с перечнем имен.
если это поможет

Comment: Или собрать его на месте. а за тем использовать его в цикле